# Can I change the media query using javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a style.css with a media query. In my javascript-file, I have a value for the desired mobile-width stored in a variable.

By changing the variable, I want to change the value of the media query automatically. Is it somehow possible to alter the contents of the .css-file with javascript like I can change the DOM? 
Adding a HTML `<style>`-element to the DOM using javascript is not my desired solution, because I want to keep all css in the .css-file

Comment: No it is not possibile. Why don't you write different media queries for different width?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no you cannot. What you can do, however, is add or remove a css class via javascript on the targeted element.

Comment: You can use  window.matchMedia() to detect any change in media query in JS

Comment: @asprin _"As far as I'm aware, no you cannot."_ It is possible by setting `.media.mediaText` of  `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` http://plnkr.co/edit/qzLO5J4KlWZLQnjMIy7i?p=preview

Answer (score 9):

The best option would be to have two sets of media queries which are only applied based on a parent class being present.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

  .w600 .myDiv{
    color:red;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 400px) {

  .w400 .myDiv{
    color:red;
  }

}
```

You could then add/remove `w600` or `w400` to the `body` class to allow the required media query to work.

Using jQuery this could be done like:

```
$("body").addClass("w600")
         .removeClass("w400");
```

---

I appreciate you may have more than just one style and would therefore like to reduce code duplication.

In which case you could use a CSS transpiler such as [Less](http://lesscss.org/) with mixins:

```
@mediaqueryruleset:{
  .myDiv{
    color:red;
  }
  .myOtherDiv{
    color:blue;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

  .w600 {
    @mediaqueryruleset();
  }

}

@media (max-width: 400px) {

  .w400 {
    @mediaqueryruleset();
  }

}
```

Which would output:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .w600 .myDiv {
    color: red;
  }
  .w600 .myOtherDiv {
    color: blue;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .w400 .myDiv {
    color: red;
  }
  .w400 .myOtherDiv {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Curt _"You cannot dynamically change a media query variable within a CSS file (without injecting the whole stylesheet again through javascript"_ The media query variable can be dynamically changed using `.media.mediaText` of `document.styleSheet` `.cssRules` http://plnkr.co/edit/qzLO5J4KlWZLQnjMIy7i?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks I wasn't aware you could do that. I still wouldn't suggest it as a viable option however. There's a lot of dependencies on the order of the stylesheets / media queries.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the rule directly using `.media.mediaText` of `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules`

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].media.mediaText = /* new media rule here */;
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/qzLO5J4KlWZLQnjMIy7i?p=preview

Comment: There's an error when setting that property, `Error: Permission denied to access property "mediaText"`, but I am able to set `conditionText`.

`document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].conditionText = "(min-width: 0px)";`

Comment: Beware that this can fail due to CORS security policy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993633/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-read-the-cssrules-property

Answer (score 1):

You can write by using `$(window).width()`

```
value=959;

if($(window).width() < value)
{
    $(".classname").css("color","white");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but since there are hundreds of values in that media query, I would need to make hundreds of css-changes in javascript. Can I say somethign like $(MEDIAQUERY).maxWidth(variableValue); ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Maybe. Inspired by @guest271314 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39611257/441016). This seems to allow the changing of the media query conditions via JavaScript.

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].conditionText = "(min-width: 0px)";
```

Of course, check if the rule has media query applied:

```
var currentQuery = {index:0,rule:null,mediaText:null};
var inclusionQuery = "(min-width: 0px)";
var exclusionQuery = "(min-width: 99999px)";
var numberOfMediaQueries = 0;

function hideAllMediaQueries() {
    var rules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    var firstQueryIndex = 0; // show this query
    var queryIndex = 0;
    var numberOfRules = rules!=null ? rules.length : 0;

    // loop through rules and hide media queries except selected
    for (var i=0;i<numberOfRules;i++) {
        var rule = rules[i];

        if (rule.media!=null) {

            if (queryIndex==firstQueryIndex) {
                currentQuery.mediaText = rule.conditionText;
                currentQuery.index = firstQueryIndex;
                currentQuery.rule = rule;
                rule.conditionText = inclusionQuery;
            }
            else {
                rule.conditionText = exclusionQuery;
            }

            queryIndex++;
        }
    }

    numberOfMediaQueries = queryIndex;
}
```

Note: The example above only applies to existing media queries in your CSS. It does not add or remove queries. It checks if media query exists by checking that the `rule.media` property is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) jQuery plugin.

It is a JavaScript library for dealing with media queries in JavaScript.

**This is quick start code sample:**

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:45em)", {

    // OPTIONAL
    // If supplied, triggered when a media query matches.
    match : function() {},      

    // OPTIONAL
    // If supplied, triggered when the media query transitions 
    // *from a matched state to an unmatched state*.
    unmatch : function() {},    

    // OPTIONAL
    // If supplied, triggered once, when the handler is registered.
    setup : function() {},    

    // OPTIONAL, defaults to false
    // If set to true, defers execution of the setup function 
    // until the first time the media query is matched
    deferSetup : true,

    // OPTIONAL
    // If supplied, triggered when handler is unregistered. 
    // Place cleanup code here
    destroy : function() {}

});
```