# Change max-width of a media query programmatically (Javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), screen and (max-width: 552px) {
    .class1 {

    }

    .class2 {

    }

    .class3 {

    }

    .class4 {

    }

    .class5 {

    }
}
```

I have the above strucutre in my css file.
What I'm trying to implement is that I have a button. When I click on that button, I need to change the `max-width: 552px` to `max-width: 1000px`. Is that possible?

Comment: Great question! The quick answer is no.

Comment: Thanks, @admcfajn

Comment: What you can really do is toggle a class. Factor out those rules and namespace them under a separate class you can use for this.

Comment: You could use multiple style sheets and switch between them.

Comment: Search your question more here on Stack. I found this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39611257/8878472

Answer (score 0):

You mean, after click the button you device screen is change? into 1000px ?
if not..

You can change the attribute 552px to 1000px, but this is depent on your screen device.

Comment: Yes. Once I click the button, the value should change to 1000px

Comment: <style>
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

a:active {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

a:target {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
-----------
<a id="btn" href="#btn">Demo</a>

like this?

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

a:active {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

a:target {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a id="btn" href="#btn">Demo</a>
```

Hi Viviek..
This is help you?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your answers. However, I figured out another way to do this. I did the below to achieve the result.

**For size = 552px**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), screen and (max-width: 552px) {
    .class1 {

    }

    .class2 {

    }

    .class3 {

    }

    .class4 {

    }

    .class5 {

    }
}
```

**For size = 1000px**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    full-screen .class1 {

    }

    full-screen .class2 {

    }

    full-screen .class3 {

    }

    full-screen .class4 {

    }

    full-screen .class5 {

    }
}
```

Now, whenever I click the button, I just need to call the below code.
`$("body").addClass("full-screen")`

**Done!**