# How to change media query CSS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have two background images and I want to change this with jQuery.

For the `#banner` it works, but I don't now how to write the code for the `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)`

```css
.banner {
  background: url(../images/640px.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .banner {
    background: url(../images/900px.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
  }
}
```

```js
var selectData = {

  "bmw": {

    "1": "316i",
    "100": "520i",
    "101": "740i",
    "image1": "images/640px.jpg",
    "image2": "images/900px.jpg",

  },

};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.specialLink', function(event) {
    var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
    if (radio2.checked == false) {
      radio2.checked = true;
      toggleRadio();
    }
    $(".regio").html($(this).text());
    event.preventDefault();
    var b = $(this),
      background_image = '';
    buttonId = b.attr('id'),
      selectSet = selectData[buttonId],
      selectField = $('#specialLink');
    selectField.empty();
    //To change the background image of website
    $("#banner").css('background-image', 'url("' + selectSet.image1 + '")');
    $("@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)").css('background-image', 'url("' + selectSet.image2 + '")');
    if (selectSet) {
      //Remove image index form selectSet
      $.each(selectSet, function(k, v) {
        if (typeof k === 'string' && k === 'image') {
          return true;
        }
        selectField.append($('<option>', {
          value: k,
          text: v
        }));
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the media query using javascript / jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609789/can-i-change-the-media-query-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery `(window).resize()` function, it will triggers when the browser window is resized.

> Here's an example using jQuery, javascript and css to handle resize events. 
>   (css if your best bet if you're just stylizing things on resize (media queries))
>   http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/LAF4G/

Use this code for the solution you needed.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024){ 
        $('.banner').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
    }   
});
```

Hope this help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image using picture tag of html5

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img1.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img2.jpg">
    <img src="img3.jpg">
</picture>
```